# In app purchase restore button doesn't cause any action?

Tags: swift, xcode, in-app-purchase

I am new to working in in-app purchases. I have set up my app to allow multiple non-consumable in-apps. If it is a first time purchase it works perfectly. If I try and click the buy button again it shows "This in-app has already been purchased etc. etc." once you click Okay, it does nothing. I have noticed it only shows "Okay" as the option and not "Cancel" and "Okay". In my test app, it shows both and works great.[image: Photo example of restore alert]`    @IBOutlet weak var buyProductID: UILabel!
    let product1 = "TestAd.com"
    @IBOutlet weak var adView1: UIView!

```
func buyProduct1(product1: SKProduct){
     print("Sending the Payment Request to Apple 1");
     let payment1 = SKPayment(product: product1)
     SKPaymentQueue.default().add(payment1);
 }

@IBAction func product1Btn(sender: AnyObject) {

   buyProductID.text = "Product1"
   print("About to fetch the product... 1")

            // Can make payments
            if (SKPaymentQueue.canMakePayments())
            {
                let productID1:NSSet = NSSet(object: self.product1);
                let productsRequest1:SKProductsRequest = SKProductsRequest(productIdentifiers: productID1 as! Set<String>);
                productsRequest1.delegate = self;
                productsRequest1.start();
                print("Fetching Products 1");
            }else{
                print("Can't make purchases 1");
            }
}


func purchase1ViewDid(){

    if (UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "purchased1")){
        adView1.isHidden = true
        print("No ads for 1")
    } else {
        print("Yes ads 1")
    }
}





func productsRequest (_ request: SKProductsRequest, didReceive response: SKProductsResponse) {

//PRODUCT 1
let count1 : Int = response.products.count
if (count1>0) {
    let validProduct1: SKProduct = response.products[0] as SKProduct
    if (validProduct1.productIdentifier == self.product1) {
        print(validProduct1.localizedTitle)
        print(validProduct1.localizedDescription)
        print(validProduct1.price)
        buyProduct1(product1: validProduct1);
    } else {
        print(validProduct1.productIdentifier)
    }
} else {
    print("nothing 1")
}
```

}

```
   func request(_ request: SKRequest, didFailWithError error: Error) {
        print("Error Fetching product information 1");
    }


    func paymentQueue(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue, updatedTransactions transactions1: [SKPaymentTransaction]) {
        print("Received Payment Transaction Response from Apple 1");



        for transaction1:AnyObject in transactions1 {
            if let trans:SKPaymentTransaction = transaction1 as? SKPaymentTransaction{
                switch trans.transactionState {
                case .purchased:


                    if buyProductID.text == "Product1" {

                        print("Product Purchased 1");
                        SKPaymentQueue.default().finishTransaction(transaction1 as! SKPaymentTransaction)
                        // Handle the purchase
                        UserDefaults.standard.set(true , forKey: "purchased1")
                        adView1.isHidden = true

                    }

                    break;
                case .failed:
                    print("Purchased Failed 1");
                    SKPaymentQueue.default().finishTransaction(transaction1 as! SKPaymentTransaction)
                    break;



                case .restored:
                    print("Already Purchased 1");
                    SKPaymentQueue.default().restoreCompletedTransactions()


                    // Handle the purchase
                    UserDefaults.standard.set(true , forKey: "purchased1")
                    adView1.isHidden = true
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Non-consumable purchases can only be purchased once, so this is the expected behavior. The message is displayed because you can only purchase the non-consumable item once, and it remains associated with the account. It thinks that since you have purchased the item already, that you simply want to restore it. As a side note, for testing purposes, IAPs have to be tested using a real device, so the simulator won't test IAPs correctly.